# Push notification based on mobile number

Tags: android

can we send notification to the device which is not having the app installed in android? Can we send notification by using the mobile number only?

Comment: It's called an SMS text message

Comment: Yes, it's called SMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Google Cloud Messaging - no.

You can send a data SMS. This type of SMS is invisible to the user but can be handled by the device to build and display a notification - it's just that the data source is not GCM but rather a plain SMS.

EDIT: Oh, nevermind, the question asks if we can do this without having your app on the device. In that case, the answer is just "no".